# Javascript canvas stroke opacity not applied to each lineto but rather continually over lines

Tags: javascript, canvas

It seems that my understanding of the javascript canvas strokestyle/line drawing is not up to par. I want to draw lines with a bit of transparency, but I fail to get the transparency applied to each and every line (segment) and instead get it sort of applied as a gradient over all the lines I've drawn...

Example code:

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var a = c.getContext('2d');

WIDTH = 400;
HEIGHT = 400;
c.width = WIDTH;
c.height = HEIGHT;;

function applyGrid()
{
    a.fillStyle = "000000";
    a.lineWidth = 2;
    a.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    a.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,200,200,0.1)";
   for (var x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x += 50)
   {
      a.moveTo(x, 0);
      a.lineTo(x, HEIGHT);
      a.stroke();
    }

}
applyGrid();​
```

See example code and (wrong) result here: http://jsfiddle.net/zKWaT/3/ I want all vertical lines to have the transparency of the rightmost line, but instead they gradually fade.

I guess I have missed something basic about how lineTo and stroke works, but having looked at examples here and there I haven't found something revealing... tt.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your for loop add `a.beginPath()` to start a new line on each loop. Otherwise you're just extending and stroking the same line over and over.

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var a = c.getContext('2d');

WIDTH = 400;
HEIGHT = 400;
c.width = WIDTH;
c.height = HEIGHT;;

function applyGrid()
{
    a.fillStyle = "000000";
    a.lineWidth = 2;
    a.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    a.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,200,200,0.1)";
   for (var x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x += 50)
   {
      a.beginPath(); //ADD THIS
      a.moveTo(x, 0);
      a.lineTo(x, HEIGHT);
      a.stroke();
    }

}
applyGrid();​
```

Comment: Nice! Do you also know why the opacity is not applied to the whole line in the previous case, but rather as a gradient?

Comment: @stackdaemon It's not applying opacity differently at all. Read this answer again, slower this time...

Comment: Whoa... Suddenly I understand.

Comment: as an alternative you could move the `a.stroke()` out of the loop so you just build one complex line and stroke it once. Since you are just using the same color, that would actually be more efficient. http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/zKWaT/4/

Comment: Thx for the tip! Ironically I tried that once in my original efforts to get it working, but had too much transparency (I realize now) for the line to be visible with only one stroke, so I was like "huh... that didnt' work at all!". Much to the non-understanding of the line drawing... :)